# Regex for splitting into sentences, ignoring decimal numbers as part of the split?

Tags: javascript, regex

In javascript, I'm interested in splitting a body of text into an array sentences, where it ignores decimal numbers (and ideally web sites) for the split.  I've found how to do it for sentences - e.g., `str.split(/[\.\!]+\s*|\n+\s*/)` - but not sure how to add the extra bit to ignore decimal numbers in the split

For example, if

```
str = "Hello there, the ice cream is $2.00.Toppings are extra."
```

Would result in

```
["Hello there, the ice cream is $2.00", "Toppings are extra"]
```

Is this possible?

thanks!

Comment: Provide sample inputs and desired output.

Comment: There's always a caveat.... *"My favourite number is 23.23 is definitely my favourite number."*

Comment: `str.split(/(?<=\d\.\d+\.)/)` ?

Comment: Because some you are using Chrome? Chrome 64+ featues regex lookbehinds.

Comment: Right, good point @wp78de

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
str = "Hello there, the ice cream is $2.00.Toppings are extra.";    
str.split(/[\.\!]+(?!\d)\s*|\n+\s*/); //[ 'Hello there, the ice cream is $2.00', 'Toppings are extra',]
```

- `(?!\d)` Zero-width negative lookahead to match `d`igit.

If the lookahead matches, The regex is not matched and the string is not splitted.

Comment: This results in one empty match `""`.

Comment: @|'-'|  your original [\.\!]+(?!\d)\s*|\n+\s* seemed to work pretty well in some initial tests

Comment: sorry - I thought I saw a difference

Answer (score 0):

Scala :

```
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;
    var regPattern = "(?<!\\d)\\.(?!\\d)|(?<=\\d)\\.(?!\\d)|(?<!\\d)\\.(?=\\d)";
    val pt = regPattern.compile(pattern);
    var strList: List[String]= pt.split(input).map(_.trim)(breakOut)
```